# Import error inside a mapper in pyspark

Tags: mapreduce, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, networkx, amazon-emr

I am working on an EMR YARN cluster an having an issue with networkx. 
I am trying to run one of the algorithms within networkx package inside a mapper, and receive an error saying there is no module name "decorator", and fails immediately, with the below error:

File "./networkx-1.11-py2.7.egg/networkx/utils/**init**.py", line 2, in 
File "./networkx-1.11-py2.7.egg/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 7, in 
**ImportError: No module named decorator**

```
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
```

It works fine when I'm running the exact script in local mode (without using the cluster).

The steps I took in order to run the code were as follows:

1. wget networkx package and its egg to the cluster.
2. installed networkx on the cluster.
3. Run my script using the command --py-files, with the path to the egg:
   *spark-submit --py-files path-to-egg/networkx-1.11-py2.7.egg --master yarn --deployed-mode cluster path-to-file/NX.py*

The issue exists only when I'm running the code on a cluster mode. It seems that for some reason, networkx egg cannot import decorator.

How do I proceed? Do I need to find another egg for decorator as well? Any other ideas regarding how to work with networkx package inside a mapper?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add another egg file, for the [`decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) package.

For instance, you could download the tarball (from the link above) and build your own egg:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

Then, you can add the path to your egg in the `--py-files` argument, e.g.

```
$ spark-submit --py-files /path/to/foo.egg,/path/to/bar.egg
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly after I generated the "decorator.egg" and added it to the command params.